# Using a list view with a Timer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating two programs that use a timer when adding data to a list view and the first program works fine but when I'm using the same code for the second program, doing basically the same it keeps throwing up an error.

This is the code;

```
var listViewItem = new ListViewItem();
listViewItem.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM:ss");
listViewItem.SubItems.Add(vitalSignData[lastReadCount].heartrate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
listViewItem.SubItems.Add(vitalSignData[lastReadCount].systolic.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

and this is the error I'm getting

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

This is my array

```
    vitalSignData = allData
                    .Select(x =>
                        new vitalSigns
                        {
                            heartrate = Convert.ToInt32(x[0]),
                            systolic = Convert.ToInt32(x[1]),
                        }).ToList();
```

Now the code I'm using and the form I'm using a identical but for some reason I'm now getting this error. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: How many entries do you have in `vitalSignData` (Length or Count) and what value has `lastReadCount` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Could you check what is being stored in the vitalSignData array, and what value lastReadCount has?

Comment: @MichaelM. My lastreadcount is set to 0 and I've added my array to my original question

Comment: vitalSignData.Count = ? / allData type? / allData.Count = ?

Comment: @MichaelM. The first program uses only one timer and enters the data from text file into the list view. My second program I'm trying to use 2 timers and enter more data into the list view than i was the first time and it doesn't appear to be liking it.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could add some snippets of code from the part with timers. You take your data from one text file? Have you tried adding a breakpoint just before listViewItem.SubItems.Add... Isn't vitalSignData.Count = 0 ?